# Python's psycopg2 & logging: Logged at the DEBUG-level queries are recorded in bytes

Tags: python, logging, encoding, psycopg2, python-logging

I have connection to PostgreSQL database:

```
LOGGER = Logger().LOGGER
# ...
self.connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=LoggingConnection,
                                   dbname=...,
                                   user=...,
                                   password=...,
                                   host=...,
                                   options="-c search_path=...")
self.connection.initialize(LOGGER)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

It's Logger class:

```
# some data

_MODE = "w"
_ENCODING = "utf-8"
_FORMATTER = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"

class Logger:
    @property
    def LOGGER(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(filename=_FILE,
                                          mode=_MODE,
                                          encoding=_ENCODING)
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_FORMATTER))
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

        return logger
# ...
```

When I execute query, it's recorded to `LOG` file in bytes, not casual string, so cyrillic characters are not displayed exclicitly. Here is an example:

```
2022-12-15 03:47:59,914 DEBUG [extras.py:427] b"INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb0')"
```

which corresponds to: `INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Кириллица')` (just some test data).

So is there any way to decode bytes? Everything is fine with logging another events not related to executing queries (DEBUG).

Thanks in advance.

Expecting something like this:

```
2022-12-15 03:47:59,914 DEBUG [extras.py:427] INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Кириллица')
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how you are logging the query please?

Comment: @snakecharmerb In the code above I do not log them manually. By manually I mean something like this:
`LOGGER.debug(query)`
I initialized LoggingConnection from psycopg2:
`from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection`
which logs all executed queries automatically, but in bytes, not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. I decided not to use `LoggingConnection` and created method which execute queries and log them the way I want:

```
def execute(self, query: str) -> tuple | None:
    """
    """
    from contextlib import closing
    with closing(self.connection) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor.execute(query)
                LOGGER.debug(query)
            except:
                # catch my exceptions here
```

I don't know how competent this solutions is, but it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to the logger to decode the bytes:

```py
class DecodingFilter:
    # Provide the correct encoding if your connection is not using UTF-8.
    def __init__(self, encoding='utf-8'):
        self.encoding = encoding

    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg.decode(self.encoding)
        return record

logger.addFilter(DecodingFilter())
```

For me, using Python 3.11 and psycopg2 2.9.5, this test code:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger')
logger.addFilter(DecodingFilter())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig()

with psycopg2.connect(dbname='test', connection_factory=extras.LoggingConnection) as conn:
    conn.initialize(logger)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT 1')
```

generates this output:

```
DEBUG:test_logger:SELECT 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. `msg` is already str. I found [ticket](https://psycopg.lighthouseapp.com/projects/62710/tickets/197-python-3-cursorquery-returns-bytes-instead-of-str), where it's said that `mogrify()` _and_ `query` _represent the statement to be sent/just sent to the server, hence it is always bytes even if the query was unicode, both in Py2 and Py3_. So, probably, there is no explicit solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It's still possible to decode the bytes in a filter (although it may be more useful to see the actual bytes sent).  I've added an example of my output.